# How to obtain the name of a month from a number?

Tags: angular

I have an array of numbers representing the index of a month, monthArr = [1, 2, 3 , …] and I want to display it in a table using the ngFor directive. When I try,

```
<tr *ngFor="let month of monthArr">
   <td>{{ month | date: 'MMMM' }}</td>
</tr>
```

The only output I get is “January”. I cannot find my mistake, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePipe` accepts `Date, a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or ISO string` type as a parameter ([Angular - DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#datepipe)),
you might want to try modifying your `monthArr` as following:

```
public monthArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].map(x => new Date(0, x));
```